# Sort Dict in Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am new to Python, I have seen many examples but not a good summary of examples. Here are the 4 things that I want to get done.  Thanks for your help.

```
mydict = {'carl':40,
          'alan':2,
          'bob':1,
          'danny':3}
```

I wanted to use the following to access the dict elements:

```
for key in sorted(mydict.keys()):
    print(key, mydict[key])
```

How do I get the following output:

Case 1: (by key ascending)

```
alan   2
bob    1
carl  40
danny  3
```

Case 2: (by key descending)

```
danny  3
carl   40
bob    1
alan   2
```

Case 3: (by value ascending)

```
bob   1
alan  2
danny 3
carl 40
```

Case 4:  (by value descending)

```
carl   40
danny   3
alan    2
bob     1
```

Comment: Turn your eyes a bit towards the right.  You'll find several questions that answer this.

Comment: @devnull I've always wondered how the StackOverflow search is so bad, but there are always so many very relevant 'related' questions in the sidebar.

Comment: @AlexThornton I agree that the search is not only bad, it's _too bad_.  However, the fact that relevant 'related' questions appear on the right exhibits that the same questions are asked over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documentation for `sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted).

Ascending by key:

```
for key, value in sorted(mydict.items()):
    pass
```

Descending by key:

```
for key, value in sorted(mydict.items(), reverse=True):
    pass
```

Ascending by value:

```
def get_value(item):
    return item[1]

for key, value in sorted(mydict.items(), key=get_value):
    pass
```

Descending by value:

```
for key, value in sorted(mydict.items(), key=get_value, reverse=True):
    pass
```

You could also use `key=lambda x: x[1]` instead of defining a `get_key` function if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'carl':40,
      'alan':2,
      'bob':1,
      'danny':3}

ks = sorted(d.keys()) #  sort keys
for key in ks:# key ascending
print(key, d[key])


for key in ks[::-1]: #key descending
    print(key, d[key])


vs= sorted(d, key=d.get) # sort keys by values
for key in vs: # values ascending
    print(key, d[key])


for key in vs[::-1]: # values descending
    print(key, d[key])
```